Как в поле ChoiceType в Symfony Forms разрешить пользователю написать свой вариант?
Создала форму на symfony и одно из полей имеет тип ChoiceType с несколькими вариантами выбора, которые я предоставила.
Но что если пользователь захочет написать свой вариант, как можно дать пользователю такую возможность в поле с этим типом?
Спасибо

Если не ошибаюсь, то в поле с этим типом никак, так как оно предназначено для создания списков с предложенными опциями.
